# How do I prove that this set is non-convex without just plugging in values for the vectors?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis

I have a set $S=\{(r_i, r_j)|\|r_i - r_j \|_2 \geq r \}$ where $r_i,r_j \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I would like to show that this set is non-convex. By following the approach of taking a linear combination of two elements of the set I get the following:

$v_1 = (r_i,r_j)$ and $v_2 = (r_k, r_z)$ where $v_1,v_2 \in S$.

$\therefore$ $\|r_i - r_j\|_2 \geq r$ and $\|r_k - r_z\|_2 \geq r$.

Now a linear combination of the elements is $v_3 = \theta v_1 + (1-\theta)v_2$  where $0 \leq \theta \leq 1 $

$\therefore v_3 = \theta(r_i, r_j) + (1-\theta)(r_k, r_z)$

$\therefore v_3 = (\theta r_i + (1-\theta)r_k, \theta r_j + (1-\theta)r_z)$

Now to check whether $v_3 \in S $, I need to check whether

$\| \theta r_i + (1-\theta)r_k - \theta r_j - (1-\theta)r_z \| \geq r $ ??

I am not sure how to use the fact that $\|r_i - r_j\|_2 \geq r$ and $\|r_k - r_z\|_2 \geq r$, and by picking a value of theta show that $v_3$ is not in $S$.

Comment: A counterexample is the classic way to prove a set is not convex. In fact, proving that a set is non-convex is tantamount to proving the existence of a counterexample to convexity. If the simplest proof of existence is to provide a concrete witness, why would you reject that kind of proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general $v_1 = (r_i,r_j)$ and $v_2 = (r_k, r_z)$ where $v_1,v_2 \in S,$
the desired value of $\theta$ may not exist.

Take $r_i = (2,2),$ $r_j = (2,-2),$ $r_k = (-2,2),$ and $r_z = (-2,-2).$

Then for any real number $\theta,$
setting $v_3 = \theta(r_i, r_j) + (1-\theta)(r_k, r_z),$
the first component of $v_3$ is $\theta r_i + (1-\theta)r_k,$
which is on the line $y = 2$ (taking the coordinates of $\mathbb R^2$ to be $(x,y)$),
while the second component of $v_3$ is $\theta r_j + (1-\theta)r_z,$
which is on the line $y=-2.$

But a point on the line $y = 2$ will always be at a Euclidean distance at least $2$ from any point on the line $y = -2.$ So no matter what value of $\theta$ you choose, $v_3$ will be a member of $S.$

In particular, whenever $0 \leq \theta \leq 1,$ you will get a vector $v_3 \in S.$

You need to choose $v_1$ and $v_2$ specifically so that there actually is a value of $\theta$ between $0$ and $1$ for which the interpolated vector $v_3$ is not in $S.$
You can pick very concrete examples of two specific vectors (which is easy to do).
You can pick less concrete but still limited examples using some parameterized vectors (still relatively easy to do).

You can also set about characterizing the set of all $(v_1,v_2)\in S^2$ such that the segment interpolated between $v_1$ and $v_2$ passes outside $S,$ and then prove that the set you have described actually does have the property that for all $(v_1,v_2)\in S^2$ that the segment interpolated between $v_1$ and $v_2$ passes outside $S.$
But that seems like extreme overkill for a proof of non-convexity.